python only appends 1 row of CSV to two-dimensional array
I'm writing code where I store employees information as a CSV file and then append it to a two-dimensional array inside python. However I only get the first row appended. As well as when I enter a name of an employee it gives me the error: Index Error: list index outside of range.
I have three modules, Main:
import UserInput
import csv
import CSVManager
import os

CSVManager.createArray()

print(CSVManager.employee_storage)

UserInput.askUser()

CSVManager.findEmployee(CSVManager.employee_storage, UserInput.userInput)

UserInput:
userInput = ""

def askUser(userInput = ""):
    userInput = input("Enter the name of the employee: ")
    return userInput

and CSVManager:
import csv
import os

employee_storage = [[]]

def createArray():
    with open('/Users/lukabramwell/Code/employee.csv', 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        for row in reader:
            employee_storage.append(row)
            print(row)
            return employee_storage
    
def findEmployee(employee_storage, userInput):
    for employee in employee_storage:
        if userInput == employee[0]:
            print(employee)
            print("Employee name: ", employee[1])
            print("Position: ", employee[2])
            print("Monday Hours: ", employee[3])
            print("Tuesday Hours: ", employee[4])
            print("Wednesday Hours: ", employee[5])
            print("Thursday Hours: ", employee[6])
            print("Friday Hours: ", employee[7])
            print("Saturday Hours: ", employee[8])
            print("Sunday Hours: ", employee[9])
        else:
            print("Employee not found")
            return None

I'm not sure if the IndexError and the fact it only appends one row is correlated or not.
Here is what my CSV file looks like:

I'm fairly new still and it's my first time working with 2d arrays so I don't know what to try first.
edit:
I've tried what you guys have said and the IndexError is now gone, aswell as the 2darray is working as intended, however it always seems to output "Employee not found" even when the current name for an employee is entered.
Main:
import UserInput
import csv
import CSVManager
import os

CSVManager.createArray()

UserInput.askUser()

CSVManager.findEmployee(CSVManager.employee_storage, UserInput.savedUserInput)

print(CSVManager.employee_storage)

UserInput:
global savedUserInput
savedUserInput = ""

def askUser(savedUserInput = ""):
    savedUserInput = input("Enter the name of the employee: ").lower()
    return savedUserInput

CSVManager:
import csv
import os
#create array to store employee data from CSV
employee_storage = []

#employeeStorageTest = [["0", "Cooper Trouper", "Barista", "9", "9", "9", "0", "9", "6", "10"], ["1", "Mario Mushroom", "Manager", "11", "8", "9", "9", "0", "5", "5"], ["2", "William Bullet", "Cleaner", "12", "9", "0", "9", "6", "9", "9"], ["3", "Rosa Lina", "Manager", "4", "4", "4", "4", "14", "0", "12"]]

#Creates the array and stores the data in the array above
def createArray():
    #Opens CSV in reader mode
    with open('/Users/lukabramwell/Code/employee.csv', 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        #This appends each row of the CSV to the array
        for row in reader:
            employee_storage.append(row)
    return employee_storage


#Function that finds a specific employee within the array using a user input
def findEmployee(employee_storage, userInput):
    #This loop goes through each employee until it finds a match and prints all of the data of the employee.
    for employee in employee_storage:
        if userInput == employee[1]:
            print("Employee name: ", employee[1])
            print("Position: ", employee[2])
            print("Monday Hours: ", employee[3])
            print("Tuesday Hours: ", employee[4])
            print("Wednesday Hours: ", employee[5])
            print("Thursday Hours: ", employee[6])
            print("Friday Hours: ", employee[7])
            print("Saturday Hours: ", employee[8])
            print("Sunday Hours: ", employee[9])
        #If no matches are found it ends and prints a message
        else:
            print("Employee not found")
            return None

Ive tried setting everything to lowercase, however the "else" code is still produced.

You have return employee_storage inside the for loop, so it only iterates once and exits the function at the end of the first iteration. Unindent it by one level to place it outside the loop. Your IndexError is likely the result of you trying to access a column of the row that it does not have. You should add the full error message and some example data for a more specific answer.

userInput never changes. You’re treating it as a global and need global userInput in the askUser function (although a better design would be to get rid of the separate file and just ask for the input directly instead).

To append all rows, change the indentation of return statement in def createArray()
    def createArray():
    with open('/Users/lukabramwell/Code/employee.csv', 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        for row in reader:
            employee_storage.append(row)
            print(row)
        return employee_storage

I am not exaclty sure why or how do you get a list index out of range error. Could you please add the error message and stack trace to your question?
Anyways your findEmployee should be changed as follows (assuming you only want to find one matching employee, i.e. first matching employee),
def findEmployee(employee_storage, userInput):
    for employee in employee_storage:
        if userInput == employee[0]:
            print(employee)
            print("Employee name: ", employee[1])
            print("Position: ", employee[2])
            print("Monday Hours: ", employee[3])
            print("Tuesday Hours: ", employee[4])
            print("Wednesday Hours: ", employee[5])
            print("Thursday Hours: ", employee[6])
            print("Friday Hours: ", employee[7])
            print("Saturday Hours: ", employee[8])
            print("Sunday Hours: ", employee[9])
            return
        
     print("Employee not found")
     return None


In the createArray() function you're returning after appending the first row, which prematurely exits the loop, so it only appends the first row. To fix this you need to change the indentation so that it returns after the loop finishes.
def createArray():
    with open('/Users/lukabramwell/Code/employee.csv', 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        for row in reader:
            employee_storage.append(row)
            print(row)
    # return employee_storage after reading loop has finished
    return employee_storage

In your findEmployee() function, the reason you may be getting an Index Error might be because you are trying to access a column in your csv that doesn't exist. I noticed your input asks for employee name, and you check that against the variable employee[0], but when you print the employee's name, you print employee[1], so the indexes your accessing might be to high, and you can fix that by lowering each index number. You can also check if len(employee) < 9 (or whatever length it's supposed to be) to prevent this error. You're also returning None as soon as the loop finds an employee that doesn't match the user input, which breaks out of the loop prematurely again. You can fix this by creating a variable to check if an employee was found.
def findEmployee(employee_storage, userInput):
    found = False
    for employee in employee_storage:
        if len(employee) < 9:
            print("Not enough columns")
        elif userInput == employee[0]:
            print(employee)
            print("Employee name: ", employee[0])
            print("Position: ", employee[1])
            print("Monday Hours: ", employee[2])
            print("Tuesday Hours: ", employee[3])
            print("Wednesday Hours: ", employee[4])
            print("Thursday Hours: ", employee[5])
            print("Friday Hours: ", employee[6])
            print("Saturday Hours: ", employee[7])
            print("Sunday Hours: ", employee[8])
            found = True
    # is no employee was found, print message
    if not found:
        print("Employee not found")
        return None

Another problem with your code is that your UserInput script doesnt change the userInput variable inside of it. This is because there is a both a parameter and a global variable called userInput, so python will change the local variable userInput instead of the global one. You can fix this by renaming the global variable.
# where the user input is saved
savedUserInput = ""

def askUser(userInput = ""):
    savedUserInput = input("Enter the name of the employee: ")
    return savedUserInput

If you do this, remember to change
CSVManager.findEmployee(CSVManager.employee_storage, UserInput.userInput)

to
CSVManager.findEmployee(CSVManager.employee_storage, UserInput.savedUserInput)

in your main module
